# How to put GROUP BY in sql statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, group-by

```
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM user, education, preference, additional, experience
        WHERE

        user.user_idx = education.edu_user AND 
        education.edu_user = preference.pref_user AND 
        preference.pref_user = additional.add_user AND 
       additional.add_user = experience.exp_user AND "
     .$user_sql_join.$edu_sql_join.$pref_sql_join.$add_sql_join.$exp_sql_join.$select_none_sql;
```

I don't know how to include `GROUP BY` for the following SQL statement.Please do help me to figure out this. I'm doing the searching function using `JOIN` STATEMENT.

Comment: I assume the php variable have text that dictate the JOIN?  Have you tried simply "GROUP BY xxx" where xxx is a column name.  Though I see you are not listing columns but select ALL columns.  If you have some that are the same name you might get an error due to ambiguous column names.  In that case, xxx might have to be y.xxx where y is the table name.

Comment: Attempting to answer this without knowing the content of the last line just seems ridiculous. But seeing as you include no aggregating functions, GROUP BY seems irrelvant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `GROUP BY` at the end of your query only with the fields that you have specified after the `SELECT` . you cannot use it with `SELECT * ...`

For example -

```
SELECT user.user_idx FROM user, education, preference, additional, experience
        WHERE

        user.user_idx = education.edu_user AND 
        user.user_idx= preference.pref_user AND 
        preference.pref_user = additional.add_user AND 
       additional.add_user = experience.exp_user 
GROUP BY user.user_idx
```

This query will group the results by the `user.user_idx` field

Answer (score 0):

to get hte result of `user.user_idx`

```
SELECT user.user_idx FROM user, education, preference, additional, experience
        WHERE

        user.user_idx = education.edu_user AND 
        user.user_idx= preference.pref_user AND 
        preference.pref_user = additional.add_user AND 
       additional.add_user = experience.exp_user 
GROUP BY user.user_idx
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some form of aggregation like SUM() AVG() MAX() etc to use GROUP BY.
eg

```
SELECT COUNT(user.user_idx) FROM user, education, preference, additional, experience
WHERE
user.user_idx = education.edu_user AND 
education.edu_user = preference.pref_user AND 
preference.pref_user = additional.add_user AND 
additional.add_user = experience.exp_user
GROUP BY education.edu_idx
```

This will give you user counts for each education.edu_idx assuming user_idx and edu_id

Without an aggregation, GROUP BY does not do much: if you don't have an aggregation you probably should just try sorting. ie use SORT BY